# Deduction of the expectation for lack of fit test

Tags: regression

**I don't understand that in the answer of 4.21,why $(E(y_{ij}))^2$ is lost when calculating $E(y_{ij}^2)$ which is shown in the third row. What's more, in the last row, where does the second term come from?**
[image]

Comment: For your first question, suppose a random variable $X$ has mean 0. What is the relationship between the variance and $E[X^2]?$

Comment: It is equal.But we suppose that variable Y obeys Normal Distribution on the same point X and its sum after standardized obeys Chi-square Distribution.So E[y^2] may not be zero.

Comment: E[y^2] is almost never going to be zero. E[ysubij^2] became sigma^2.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a typo in your solution.

[image]

Comment: As this appears in my browser (Chrome) part of the text appears in what I think is Korean. Can you edit it?

Comment: The Korean sentences mean 'According to the data structure for the lack-of-fit inference, $E(y_{ij})=E(y_i)$', 'and so'. Those are in the picture, not text form so I can't edit it.