# Derivation of $\mathbb{E}\lbrack MSLF \rbrack$ in lack of fit test

Tags: regression

I'm currently studying the lack of fit test in a linear regression course. I'll define a few things here, then state precisely what it is I'm trying to derive.

$$SSE = \sum_{i = 1}^c \sum_{j = 1}^{n_i} (y_{ij}-\hat{y}_{ij})^2 $$

$$ SSLF = \sum_{i = 1}^c \sum_{j = 1}^{n_i}(\overline{y}_i - \hat{y}_{ij})^2 $$

$$ SSPE = \sum_{i = 1}^c \sum_{j = 1}^{n_i}(y_{ij} - \overline{y}_{i})^2 $$

$$ MSLF = \frac{SSLF}{c-2} $$
$$ MSPE = \frac{SSPE}{n-c} $$

I wish to derive the following:
$$ \mathbb{E} \left\lbrack MSLF \right\rbrack = \sigma^2 + \frac{1}{c-2} \sum_{i=1}^{c} n_i (\mathbb{E}\lbrack y_{ij} \rbrack -(\beta_0 + \beta_1 x_i))^2 \tag{$\star$}$$

We have

$$ \mathbb{E} \left\lbrack MSLF \right\rbrack = \frac{1}{c-2} \mathbb{E} \left\lbrack SSLF \right\rbrack$$

and since $SSE = SSLF + SSPE,$

$$ \mathbb{E} \left\lbrack SSLF \right\rbrack = \mathbb{E} \left\lbrack SSE \right\rbrack - \mathbb{E} \left\lbrack SSPE \right\rbrack.$$

I was able to derive $\mathbb{E}(SSPE) = (n-c)\sigma^2.$ But I cannot finish the derivation for $\mathbb{E}(SSE).$ I figure if this can be done, I will have completed a derivation of $\mathbb{E}\lbrack SSLF \rbrack$. I want to show that $1/(c-2) \mathbb{E}\lbrack SSLF \rbrack$ is equivalent to the expression in $(\star)$.

How is this one done?

Comment: So are you trying to derive $E[MSLF]$ or $E[SSE]$ or both?

Comment: Please add the self-study tag and I'll add a hint in the answer.

Comment: Specifically, I'm trying to derive $\mathbb{E}\lbrack MSLF \rbrack.$ The post here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/122328/deduction-of-the-expectation-for-lack-of-fit-test near the bottom mentions a computation for $\mathbb{E}\lbrack SSE \rbrack$ being useful for this.

Comment: Is there a specific results you are trying to obtain? $E[MSLF]$ can be expressed in several different ways.

Comment: Yes, the version I'm trying to derive is the one in the question. This specific form is mentioned in Applied Linear Statistical Models (5ed.) in a comment without proof, so I'm trying to do it.

Comment: Page number?  I have that book.

Comment: BTW, this wasn't clear from your question.  In the question you said you "know that" so I assumed you could already show this.

Comment: It appears on page 126, in the Comments section. Thanks for your help, it's bugging me that I can derive the top equality but not the bottom. The post I linked above mentions using E(SSE) to do this after computing E(MSPE), but I didn't get anywhere with that.

Comment: Yes.  I see it now.  Give me minute.  There's a method to prove this using the trick I mentioned below.  I'll derive this and post back.

Comment: So, can you pleased it the question by adding at the very end exactly what you are trying to prove?  The way it's worded now, it's not clear to me and may not be to other users. Just a single sentence that says something like, "I need help showing $LHS=RHS$."

Comment: Edited, hopefully it is more clear now.

Comment: Thanks, @dove!  Will post back late tonight if someone doesn't beat me to it -- off to dinner. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hint for your self-study question:

To prove $E[SSLF]=E[SSE]−E[SSPE]$, try adding and subtracting $\bar{y}_i$ from the terms in parenthesis of SSE and use algebra to group like terms, noting that the cross product terms vanish to zero.